# MySQL - Concat to a calculated result

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I have a query that divides 2 different queries into 1 result, resulting in a decimal number, i.e. 5.14. I'd like to add the percent sign to the end. So, the result is 5.14%. I tried to `CONCAT()` but got errors.

Heres my fist part of the query:

```
SELECT ((o.count_1 / s.count_2) * 100) as '% of # of Ops to # of Users Ratio'
```

Comment: you know... you can't enclose column names in quotes (`'`). If you want to specify a column name with spaces (or other things), use backticks ```

Comment: It's so helpful when someone downrates your question but doesn't leave why? That's so helpful. Tried the given answers and they result in the same, what seems to be an encrypted record, starting with 0x352... I'm trying to simply add the percent sign at the end of the result.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how exactly you tried `COUNCAT()`. Try it this way

```
SELECT CONCAT(((o.count_1 / s.count_2) * 100), '%') AS `% of # of Ops to # of Users Ratio`
  FROM ...
```

or if you need to round the result then

```
SELECT CONCAT(ROUND(((count_1 / count_2) * 100), 2), '%') AS `% of # of Ops to # of Users Ratio`
  FROM ...
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76ac5/3)** demo

Comment: Tried these both and resulted in what looks to be like an encrypted record, starting with 0x352... Using lynqpad

Comment: Did you try your query in plain mysql client? Did you take a look at sqlfiddle examples I provided? In order to help you more you have to provide table schema and sample data on which you get these "encrypted" results. And you didn't tell what errors you got in the first place.

Comment: @Phil Did it work out in the end? DO you need more help with your question?

Comment: No, at least not in LINQPad

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(((o.count_1 / s.count_2) * 100), '%') AS '% of # of Ops to # of Users Ratio'
```

Or...

```
SELECT CONCAT(((o.count_1 / s.count_2) * 100), '% of # of Ops to # of Users Ratio')
```

Not sure if you wanted that `'% of # of Ops to # of Users Ratio'` as part of the result or as the column name.